# Unresolved external symbol bcrypt_gensalt

Tags: c, windows, linker-errors, cng

I have one problem with library `<bcrypt.h>`. Compiler say error with function `bcrypt_gensalt`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bcrypt.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    const char* passwd = "Secret_Password";

    char results[BCRYPT_HASHSIZE];

    bcrypt_gensalt(10, results);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Error from compiler:

```
unresolved external symbol bcrypt_gensalt referenced in function main
```

Comment: Add `#pragma comment (lib, "bcrypt.lib")` to the source file outside of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference Bcrypt.lib.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx.